# What are natural sources of longwave radiation

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, waves, reflection

I am studying now the Earth radiation balance and I came across the question regarding the sources of the long-wave radiation on earth surface. The only source of theses wavelengths indicated in the book are clouds, which have high reflectivity and reflect a part of the long-wave radiation. I am looking for some other sources of it.

I was thinking that CO2 can be another source because of this greenhouse effect.

Are there any other major global sources which can bring long-wave radiation into earth system>

Answer (score 1):

Not sure hat you mean by "longwave" radiation; everyone would have a different idea.

If you mean approximately 10 micron wavelength region Infra red radiation; virtually everything on earth at ordinary environmental temperatures is a source of that.

Comment: I was thinking about the heat. I am looking for some major sources which could influence the climate.

Comment: Try looking at the sun, as a source of electromagnetic radiation energy, which gets mostly converted into waste "heat" energy here on earth.  That might have a big influence on the climate.